# How large can be $|\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\chi(n)|$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, reference-request

How large can be $|\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\chi(n)|$ if the [Dirichlet character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) $\chi$ is not principal?

If $\chi$ is the principal, then we can use the theory of [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), and there are many estimates.

If $\chi$ is not principal, it is well known that $\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu(n)\chi(n)}{n} = O(1)$. Are there any Tauberian theorems to estimate $|\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \mu(n)\chi(n)|$?

Also, DGF $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)\chi(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p} (1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s})$ is considered. However, the RHS seems not to be a closed-form, therefore it seems that the [Wiener-Ikehara theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem) cannot be applied here.

Here is a similar [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82510/the-correlation-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-function-and-dirichlet-characters), but I don't think it answers my question. Maybe I can do some numerical programming jobs, but before that, I am curious whether there are some references or nice constructions?

Comment: The Dirichlet series is $1/L(s, \chi)$, which is analytic at $1$. I presume that imitating the proof of Siegel-Walfisz theorem will yield estimate like $o(x)$.

Comment: the usual Mertens function estimates should hold here and be obtained fairly similarly; anything better gives stuff about the continuation of $1/L$ so about the GRH, so obviously are not known; as for modulus unifomity, here I am less well versed, but I guess there are mean value results Vinogradov style when you consider all characters of a given modulus